# WebClient Cookie confusion

Tags: .net, cookies, webclient

-edit- nevermind. I ran the code again and it appears i cant log into that first site anymore. It must have been a weird cache issue or something. Maybe i overlooked something. WebClient seems to ignore cookies so logging onto a site shouldnt work.

I figured out how to login to websites using WebClient. On the first website i tried i could login and the following pages would have my login data. On another site this was no the case and i had to do this http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html

What is the rule about cookies in webclient and why does this site work only with the alternative webclient class?

Comment: Mind I ask you which website are you trying to login to? By any chance Hotmail? Because I'm working on the same problem and am about to give up. Btw if you need help logging into Yahoo or Gmail, let me know.

Comment: @niaher: You should use POP or IMAP instead.

Comment: @niaher: Nah, its just a test to understand WebClient better. The site i was able to loginto was mine so when SLaks said there may be a security hole i wanted to poke him and see what more he'll say. The other site i tested i already had login code using HttpWebRequest so i just grabbed that and tested using WebClient instead. I still dont know why cookies doesnt appear to login for the 2nd site. If you have ready code to loginto yahoo or gmail i'd definitely like to see it just to know if i need to use that handling cookies trick with those website or not.

Comment: And what SLaks said. On request i made an app for someone to automatically check their gmail and with an IMAP library it was incredibly easy.

Comment: Actually in my case I needed login in order to retrieve user's contacts, so I used OAuth protocol. Not exactly a login though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebClient` completely ignores cookies.

If there is a website which can be logged in to with a normal `WebClient`, it must be using something other than a cookie.  (And it probably has a security hole)

Comment: a security hole? I dont think so. Using Tamper Data i see the server returning a uid, tid and a httponly sid all with 64bits length. The WebClient code calls the login then several pages. I dont think it is ignoring cookies.

Comment: Run Fiddler and see exactly what's going on.

Comment: You right. It appears i cant log into the site anymore. Maybe there was some caching going on or something else i overlooked.